# Pointers and multi-dimensional arrays questions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am teaching myself C++ and and currently learning about multi-dimensional arrays. Below is the code I am using. Below the code are the questions/concepts I am having trouble with.

```
int main(){
    const unsigned row = 4, col = 4;
    int arr[row][col], cnt = 0;

    for (int(*a)[col] = arr; a != arr + col; ++a){
        for (int *b = *a; b != *a + col; ++b){
            *b = cnt;
            ++cnt;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

1. in the first line of the for statement `for (int(*a)[col] = arr;
   a != arr + col; ++a)`. Why does the `int(*a)[col] = arr;` require
   the `[col]` for the `for` loop to execute correctly?
2. in the first line of the second for statement `for (int *b = *a; b != *a + col; ++b)`. Is `*a` not dereferencing the pointer?
3. The second for statement is unclear to me as to how it work. I understand which order it executes, but I am unclear about the relationship between the first for statement and the second for statement. any clarification for would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers have a type that they point to. Except for `void *`, a pointer can only hold the address of an object of that type.

In the first line: Since you are looping over each row of the array, the pointer must point to a whole row (not to a single int).

In the second line, `*a` does dereference `a`.  `*a`. is always equivalent to `a[0]`. Since `a` points to a row, `a[0]` designates that row.

`a[0]` is an array, so when it is used to initialize `b`, it decays to a pointer to the first element of that row.

The firs tlook loops over each row; the second loop loops over ech column. It's the same structure as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
        arr[i][j] = ++cnt;
```

except you are using a pointer instead of an integer offset that is later added to a pointer.

Comment: ok, so in the second for statement `for (int *b = *a; b != *a + col; ++b)` `++b` is iterating through the addresses in memory. however, with the condition statement of `b != *a + col;` is the same as `b(memory address) != *a(dereferenced address/pointer, = to 0) + col(col = 4)` how does the for statement know when the condition is met when it is comparing a memory address `b(memory address)` to `1!= *a(now = 4, an int)` ? The words in () are to show what I know them to mean/equal.

Comment: when you use `+` on a pointer and an integer, it means to advance the pointer by that number of elements. So if `p` is pointing to the first integer, then `p + 1` is the second int, and `p + col` is one-past-the-end of the row.